# BlackBerry programming - Setting font size for label

Tags: blackberry, label, font-size

I'm trying to make the font on a LabelField the same size as the built-in digital clock on the Storm and Torch.

No matter what I set the size too, it seems to only goto a certain size and it will no longer increase.

How do I increase the font size / label width?

```
// set up custom font for timer label  
if (FontManager.getInstance().load("Digital Readout Thick Upright.ttf", "DigitalFont", FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT) == FontManager.SUCCESS) {}
try {
    FontFamily family = FontFamily.forName("DigitalFont");

    // I've tried to set it to 100 but it doesn't make any different
    Font digitalFont = family.getFont(Font.BOLD, 72); 
    lblSpotTime.setFont(digitalFont);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's just a limit of that font - you can't make it bigger than 72.  The digital clock on the Torch and the Storm probably (almost certainly) uses embedded image files to render the numbers.  If you want a label field with characters that big, you'd have to roll your own by overriding your inherited field's paint method and drawing the characters yourself, copying embedded images instead of drawing text.  This is a lot of work and I certainly don't recommend it.

Comment: On the other hand, the hidden secret of BlackBerry programming is that you can push pixels around (i.e. access low-level functionality and draw everything yourself) just as powerfully as any other mobile platform. Knock yourself out - you can't do any worse than the BlackBerry platform developers themselves.

Comment: This task seems not easy at all. Thanks MusiGenesis for your suggestion.

Comment: I think I got this solved => create a custom label field and overriding the paint() method.

Comment: Congratulations. I've been doing heavy BB coding for more than a week now myself, and I'd say learning to paint() your own fields is your only hope of producing a UI that doesn't look like the drab settings screens in BB. Pretty fun, though - you can do pretty much whatever you want.